# VSCode: Cannot find module 'antd' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, antd

I have installed antd to my typescript project:

```
"antd": "^4.6.2",
```

It works fine and my project builds using the antd components (webpack used to build) but inside VSCode I don't get typings and it gives me this error:

[image]

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?  Antd is meant to include it's own typings so why doesn't VSCode recognise it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue appears to be known issue with VSCode: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10346

It can be fixed by manually adding to the top of the file

```
/// <reference path="path/types.d.ts" />
```

Then doing F1 -> reload window.

Or apparently by installing vscode typescript hero plugin.  I can't confirm plugin works as I had already fixed with manual reference and reload.

Comment: The TypeScript Hero plugin worked for me. Just had to restart VS Code and the warnings went away.

Comment: For those unfamiliar as I was, that code is a [TypeScript Triple Slash Directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) which "are only valid at the top of their containing file." So make sure to prepend it as the first line.

Comment: @NelsonFrew Thanks for the extra context re: the triple-slash directive needing to be located at the top of the file, that was very helpful for me. Another important thing to note as per the [TypeScript "Triple-Slash Directives" doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) is that they can be preceded by comments and other TSDs, too: "Triple-slash directives are only valid at the top of their containing file. A triple-slash directive can only be preceded by single or multi-line comments, including other triple-slash directives."

Answer (score 7):

##### I installed the module, but still had this message

`F1 -> reload window` helped me

Comment: also can do `ctrl + shift + p`  to open command window and then `reload window`

Comment: It works, but why?

Answer (score 1):

add tsx file to tsconfig.json:

```
{
    ...
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "./**/*.tsx"
    ],
    ...
}
```